# getting elements of array in python with a single line

Tags: python, list, numpy

I need to work with this beautiful np array

```
import numpy as np
train_predicteds = np.asarray([ 
 [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.5, 0.6, 0.7], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]],
 [[0.3, 0.1, 0.4], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.5, 0.6, 0.1]]])
```

Now I want to get the elements in this fashion:

```
[[0.1, 0.3], [0.2, 0.1], [0.3, 0.4],
 [0.5, 0.4], [0.6, 0.5], [0.7, 0.6],
 [0.7, 0.5], [0.8, 0.6], [0.9, 0.1]]
```

Some sort of solution I found was using these two lines:

```
aux = [item[0] for item in train_predicteds]
x = [item[0] for item in aux]
```

Which produces me x equals to

```
[0.10000000000000001, 0.30000000000000001]
```

But I can't merge these two lines in a single one, is it possible? Or is there a better pythonic solution?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with:

```
In [17]: arr = np.asarray([  
    ...:  [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.5, 0.6, 0.7], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]], 
    ...:  [[0.3, 0.1, 0.4], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.5, 0.6, 0.1]]])                 
In [18]: arr                                                                    
Out[18]: 
array([[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
        [0.5, 0.6, 0.7],
        [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]],

       [[0.3, 0.1, 0.4],
        [0.4, 0.5, 0.6],
        [0.5, 0.6, 0.1]]])
In [19]: arr.shape                                                              
Out[19]: (2, 3, 3)
```

After trying several transpose orders I got:

```
In [26]: arr.transpose(1,2,0)        # shape (3,3,2) moves 1st dim to end                                          
Out[26]: 
array([[[0.1, 0.3],
        [0.2, 0.1],
        [0.3, 0.4]],

       [[0.5, 0.4],
        [0.6, 0.5],
        [0.7, 0.6]],

       [[0.7, 0.5],
        [0.8, 0.6],
        [0.9, 0.1]]])
```

The first two dimensions can be merged with reshape:

```
In [27]: arr.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(9,2)                                      
Out[27]: 
array([[0.1, 0.3],
       [0.2, 0.1],
       [0.3, 0.4],
       [0.5, 0.4],
       [0.6, 0.5],
       [0.7, 0.6],
       [0.7, 0.5],
       [0.8, 0.6],
       [0.9, 0.1]])
```

Answer (score 4):

The better Pythonic solution

```
>>> train_predicteds[:,0,0]
array([0.1, 0.3])
```

Comment: I think OP was trying to recreate the entire array from his second code block though, and was getting caught stumped how to expand his algorithm from calculating one item to the full thing. Perhaps I misunderstood though

Comment: I was able to reconstruct element by element with my "sort of a solution", but I wanted something more stylish.

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino  You should consider to accept hpaulj solution instead, it's much more "numpythonic" than the other 2 answers here.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple loop comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
train_predicteds = np.asarray([ 
 [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.5, 0.6, 0.7], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]],
 [[0.3, 0.1, 0.4], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.5, 0.6, 0.1]]])

result = [list(train_predicteds[:, i, j]) for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]
```

Output:

```
[[0.1, 0.3], [0.2, 0.1], [0.3, 0.4],
 [0.5, 0.4], [0.6, 0.5], [0.7, 0.6],
 [0.7, 0.5], [0.8, 0.6], [0.9, 0.1]]
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to [Reedinationer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10924296/reedinationer) for pointing it out

Or if you prefer a more generalized form:

```
result = [list(train_predicteds[:, i, j]) for i in range(len(train_predicteds[0])) for j in range(len(train_predicteds[0, 0]))]
```

Comment: Oush! That's nice =) Thanks, mylord!

Comment: OP may have wanted something more general like `result = [list(train_predicteds[:, x, y]) for x in range(len(train_predicteds) + 1) for y in range(len(train_predicteds[0]))]`, but this output is clean! Good job.

Comment: @Reedinationer You're right. But in my experience, usually the straight answer that solves the specific problem is more wanted

Comment: @Reedinationer, your solution had problems with this input. train_predicteds = np.asarray([
... [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.5, 0.6, 0.7], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]],
... [[0.3, 0.1, 0.4], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.5, 0.6, 0.1]],
... [[0.3, 0.1, 0.4], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.5, 0.6, 0.1]],
... [[0.3, 0.1, 0.4], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.5, 0.6, 0.1]],
... [[0.3, 0.1, 0.4], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.5, 0.6, 0.1]]])

Comment: @Amir it worked for me for the initial post, but perhaps the +1 is throwing it off. I’m on mobile now so I can’t figure it out myself. Sorry 

Comment: Relax, sir. I have this ranges pre-calculated. Can use them instead of calculating them in this line. Thanks

Comment: @Reedinationer Thanks, I fixed the small problem in your answer and added it to mine